# Разделить основные стили и media по разным файлам

Tags: gulp, less

Хочу писать **@media** в **less** файлах для каждого блока, на данный момент **less** файлы собираются в **main.css**, но я хочу что бы **@media** при сборке все соединялись по значению, например все **@media (min-width: 1024px)** и в них все стили для этого **media** из всех файлов и т.д. для каждого **media** одинакового, тут мне подошел плагин **gulp-group-css-media-queries**, он все отлично обьединяет и ставит в конце файла, но что я сделать не понимаю как, вырезать эти все **@media** в отдельный файл **responsive.css** и что бы на выходе я получил **main.css** и **responsive.css**.

На данный момент сборка less выглядит вот так:

```
function stylesdev() {
    return gulp.src(path.src.less)
        .pipe(less({ plugins: [autoprefixPlugin] }).on('error', function (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }))
        .pipe(gcmq())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(path.build.css))
        .pipe(browserSync.stream())
        .pipe(touch());
}
```

Comment: Не нашел решения и видимо с этим не сталкивались раз ответа нет, жаль, поидее идея классная, сейчас приходится писать все в один респонсиве, хотя куда удобнее было бы писать респонсив в файле относящимся к своему блоку.

Answer (score 0):

Существует решение на основе postcss плагина, который вытаскивает mq выражения в другой файл.

Имя ему **PostCSS Filter Media Queries**

Поставляется пакетом `postcss-filter-mq`

Установить `npm install --save-dev gulp-postcss postcss-filter-mq`

Простейший пример. На выходе будет `output.css` где содержаться только mq запросы.

```
var gulp = require("gulp"),
    rename = require("gulp-rename"),
    postcss = require("gulp-postcss"),
    filtermq = require("postcss-filter-mq");

gulp.task( "css:mq", function () {

    gulp.src("src/input.css")
        .pipe( postcss([ filtermq ]) )
        .pipe( rename( "output.css" ) )
        .pipe( gulp.dest("dist/") );

});
```

Простенькая документация с примерами.

- [Примеры](https://github.com/simeydotme/postcss-filter-mq/blob/master/docs/largeScreens.md)
- [Ссыль на реп](https://github.com/simeydotme/postcss-filter-mq/tree/master)